# Eclipse doesn't see my Android device

Tags: android, eclipse, driver

I just installed the Android SDK and Eclipse and then tried to launch an app from Eclipse on my real android tablet.

Clicking the "run-as" symbol in the toolbar shows "none applicable" so i used the context menu of the project file. Here i can choose "android Application" but in the opening window my device doesnt show up.

I enabled the developer mode and USB debugging and Windows installed some drivers automatically. I also tried installing the USB driver from Acers homepage manually. After connecting, the tablet shows the "USB debugging connected" in the pull down menu.
The file system can be accessed trough windows explorer, so i build the app manually and was able to copy it through windows explorer onto the tablet and then run it through androids file manager.

What can i try to get this essential feature working? Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Did you install `Kies`?

Comment: what is your tablet's model, company?

Comment: Acer Iconia, model: A1-810. It is running the latest android version. Do you mean Samsung Kies???

Comment: did you install **Google USB Driver** @ SDK Manager?

Comment: Yes, i installed all the pre-selected packages including the Google USB Driver.

Comment: No i didnt, my tablet is from Acer... Did you ask because this software causes trouble sometimes or because you think it helps?

Comment: @einUsername sorry. I miss understand.I face the same problem, with my Samsung phone till I downloaded the `Kies`. You can use this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) then choose `Acer`. and good luck

Comment: @einUsername take a look at my answer if you have spare time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) Connect your phone with your computer (Easy)

2) Enable USB debugging [How to do it](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/mobile/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-android-phone/)

3) Watch this video so as to
Install the correct drivers on your computer [How to do it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RDA8PpPSFuk)

Hope that helps!!

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick! I had to download and then select the Google ADB drivers manually in the device manager. The drivers by Acer didnt work and neither those by Renesas or the ones loaded by the Googles SDK manager.

Answer (score 3):

This is a short checklist that you need to follow:

1. download manufacturer driver from [this official link](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html) and install it;
2. be sure that you have enabled Developer Options on your device;
3. enable "Debug USB" on Developer Options;
4. go to Storage, and in options menu click "USB computer connection";
5. in USB computer connection, check "Media device (MTP);
6. check in your system bar if you have the symbol of "Debug USB" (is a KitKat on latest version, for example);
7. connect your device on PC.

If your device is showed on device list, but it is "unknown", than restart only your device.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly none of your ideas fixed it. Maybe my stupid PC is just incompatible. -.- What else can i try?

Comment: @einUsername right click on My computer, choose Properties and then go to Device Manager. Be sure to see Android Device and Mobile Device labels (of course with your device connected); if they are not there, delete and reinstall Asus driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my LG G3 phone. 
I tried to re-install the driver as explained here: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html
 Nothing helped. Fortunately on the very same page I have found the link to LG firmware site: http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware

So I did the following:

- Connect the phone to the PC using the USB cable
- Uninstalled the Google's USB driver (My Computer->Management->Devices->Portable Devices->MyPhone: uninstall)
- Download driver for my LG G3 phone (LG885) from the LG site
- Install this driver
- Got on the phone screen request to approve the new RCA key and allow debugging.
- Try to Run an Android project in Eclipse.
- PROBLEM SOLVED.